# Android SAXParse Get Value Between Tags

Tags: android, xml-parsing, sax

I have an XML file I am reading in via SAXParser, but I am having trouble reading it in correctly. The XML is structured like this:

```
<game>
  <players>
    <player>
      <name>Player 1</name>
      <score>100</score>
    </player>
  </players>
</game>
```

How can I get the Android SAXParser to read the values between tags? This is the code that I have, but it is looking for an attribute to the tag, not the text between.

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if(localName.equals("name")) {
        names.add(attributes.getValue("name"));
    }
    else if(localName.equals("score")) {    
        scores.add(Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("score")));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing from the example @

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

More info about sax @

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Apart from sax you should have a look at xmllpullparser which is recommended.

Quoting from the docs.

**We recommend XmlPullParser, which is an efficient and maintainable way to parse XML on Android**.

Check the link @

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

```
public void readxml(){ 
        try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

        boolean bname = false;
        boolean bscore = false;


        public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                bname = true;
            }

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("score")) {
                bscore = true;
            }
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
            String qName) throws SAXException {

        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

            if (bname) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), new String(ch, start, length), 10000).show();
                bname = false;
            }

            if (bscore) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), new String(ch, start, length), 10000).show();
                bscore = false;
            }
        }
      };

           saxParser.parse("myxmltoparse", handler);

         } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }

       }
}
```